# Stereo to point cloud

Tags: opencv, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a calibrated stereo camera and I would like convert images to point cloud.

I'm going to do this with opencv, with the function reprojectImageTo3D, but I need the Q matrix.

I found another function to calculate the Q matrix but I don't know some parameters:

My calibration data:

Right camera:

```
image_width: 640
image_height: 480
camera_name: 00b09d0100a8cd50
camera_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [618.406355982753, 0, 328.938909311292, 0, 622.618018605044, 192.823847411511, 0, 0, 1]
distortion_model: plumb_bob
distortion_coefficients:
rows: 1
cols: 5
data: [-0.46935852500581, 0.495020825022316, 0.0069132704108347, 0.000957659601339344, 0]
rectification_matrix:
rows: 3
cols: 3
data: [0.987794979792204, 0.000360084570829607, -0.15575926372586, -0.00147162495744743, 0.999974269489065, -0.00702101700582399, 0.155752727800526, 0.00716454457124124, 0.987770093232116]
projection_matrix:
rows: 3
cols: 4
data: [2536.3424975867, 0, 419.49533700943, 112.802583009304, 0, 2536.3424975867, 207.939946174622, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Left camera:

```
image_width: 640
image_height: 480
camera_name: 00b09d01009b8da3
camera_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [1303.84092827502, 0, 305.740018425863, 0, 1314.11682894773, 177.738196152231, 0, 0, 1]
distortion_model: plumb_bob
distortion_coefficients:
   rows: 1
   cols: 5
   data: [-0.151635456291086, 0.3629641480367, -0.00784184518383463, -0.000413869770118943, 0]
rectification_matrix:
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   data: [0.98618892981478, -0.00296598739861576, -0.165597698140795, 0.0041481493735406, 0.999968321024829, 0.006793364671487, 0.165572303141417, -0.0073864650230178, 0.986169991718928]
projection_matrix:
 rows: 3
 cols: 4
 data: [2536.3424975867, 0, 419.49533700943, 0, 0, 2536.3424975867, 207.939946174622, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

How I obtain the R and T?

```
stereoRectify(InputArray cameraMatrix1, => camera_matrix_left
              InputArray distCoeffs1, => distortion_coefficients_left
              InputArray cameraMatrix2, => camera_matrix_right
              InputArray distCoeffs2, => distortion_coefficients_right
              Size imageSize, => size of the images
              InputArray R, => ??????
              InputArray T => ??????
              OutputArray R1, OutputArray R2, OutputArray P1, OutputArray P2, OutputArray Q)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201519/stereo-to-point-cloud/) by [rcj1986](https://answers.ros.org/users/14706/rcj1986/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2015-01-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's already a package to do this built into ROS - [stereo_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc). You could use it as a reference, or just plug it into your workflow.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rcj1986](https://answers.ros.org/users/14706/rcj1986/) on 2015-01-26**:
Thanks, I'll take a look. but I am still interested.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-01-26**:
With opencv/vision type issues, you may have more luck from answers.opencv.org